# Perl query for shortest algorithm

Tags: perl

I have a text file which is something like:

```
aaa bbb_ccc
ddd ee_ff gg
hh i j kk l
aaa mm_nn_o
p qq rr ss_t
aaa uu_lfpr lkl 
dde ldk_tr_lp
```

I want to grep for any line starting with `aaa`, and everytime I find this line match, I want to copy that line and all following lines (except empty lines), until the next match, to new text files. In the example above, my new text files, that I am copying to, should look like:

**file1**

```
aaa bbb_ccc
ddd ee_ff gg
hh i j kk l
```

**file2**

```
aaa mm_nn_o
p qq rr ss_t
```

**file3**

```
aaa uu_lfpr lkl
dde ldk_tr_lp
```

Is there any short algorithm we can use to implement this? I don't want to use flags or switches to do this and make a long code. I was wondering if there is any function or any builtin subroutine which can do this with much shorter code.

Comment: Define regex for match, read whole file into variable (if the file is not too big), capture regex match into array, for each element of array open own file and _dump_ element of array into the file. Without seeing your code no help should be expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My shortest:

```
my $n = 1; # File number
while (<>) {
  open (STDOUT, '>', 'file' . $n++) if /^aaa/;
  print;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Here are a couple of sketches, until some code is shown at which point I can elaborate as needed.

The main point: There is no need for a flag. Just open a new file on each match

```
my ($cnt, $fh_out);

while (<$fh_input>) { 
   if (/^\s*aaa/) {
       ++$cnt;
       open $fh_out, '>', "file$cnt.txt" or do { warn $!, next };
   }
   print $fh $_;
}
```

Opening a filehandle closes it first if it's opened, so previous writes are safe and a new file is open.

Or, if you'd rather have a one-line regex to parse the input file

```
my $content = do { local (@ARGV, $/) = $filename; <> };

my @blocks = $content =~ /(aaa (?: (?!aaa). )+ )/sxg; 

for my $i (0..$#blocks) { 
    open my $fh, '>', 'file'.($i+1).'.txt'  or do { warn $!, next };
    print $fh $blocks[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use split

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data    = do { local $/; <> };
my @array   = split(/(?=(?:aaa))/,$data);
my $count   = 1;

for (@array) {
    open STDOUT , '>' , 'file' . $count++;
    print;
}
```

NOTE:
`open STDOUT , '>' , 'file' . $count++;` is borrowed from [ceving](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402322/ceving) -- simple approach